# wx.ListCtrl with TextEditMixin - Disable Editing of Selected Cells

Tags: python, listview, wxpython

Is there any way to disable the editing of specific cells by the user when using `ListCtrl` with `TextEditMixin`?

I guess there's some way that Vetos the editing event, however I can't find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Event wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_LABEL_EDIT:

```
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnBeginLabelEdit)

    def OnBeginLabelEdit(self, event):
        if event.m_col == 1:
            event.Veto()
        else:
            event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 2):

In wxPython version 4.0.0 the line:

`if event.m_col == 1` 
does not work. Use

`if event.GetColumn() == 1`

instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, you have to bind to EVT_LIST_BEGIN_LABEL_EDIT. Then in your event handler you just check what column you're in and if you're in a column that you want to be editable, then you do "event.Allow()", otherwise you veto.

Comment: What's the difference between `evt.Veto()` and `evt.Allow()`?

Comment: uh, Veto stops the event from going up the event chain whereas Allow let's it keep going. Now, a better question is what is the difference between Allow and Skip? That I am not sure about...

Comment: Oh my mistake that's what I wanted to ask :) from http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Phoenix/ `Allow` is "This is the opposite of Veto : it explicitly allows the event to be processed." and `Skip` is "This method can be used inside an event handler to control whether further event handlers bound to this event will be called after the current one returns.", doesn't seem like a difference except that Allow is only available on NotifyEvent's children...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's an alias. You should ask on the wxPython mailing list for an official answer though.